# Import complex ant project (or maven project) of a webapp to IntelliJ IDEA with incremental build (Eclipse would work fine as well)

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ant, build

We are making a Java webapp for tomcat. We build for production with ant and use maven for the dependencies (and for dependencies only). Build.xml has grown to something complex and oversimplifying a bit looks something like:

1. Read some build properties from a couple of .properties files
2. Clean stuff
3. Call a dozen of different ant targets that build various parts of a site such as stylesheets or several frontend JavaScripts (some of theses tasks just call shell scripts).
4. Compile Java classes
5. Copy the built classes, compiled resources, static resources to the build directory
6. Post process some stuff even more (e.g. minify something)
7. Use ant's war task to prepare the final war

That works fine for the deployment, but daily development is somewhat slow as IDEs do not support such a workflow and have own assumption on what to put where and how to assemble a war file (or exploded war file). You sure can tune that, but.. that essentially means replicating complex ant tasks with the IDE-specific settings and you'll have to build the whole thing when changing just one small resource.

**Question**
- Is there a way to "smartly" import an ant project to IDE, so that it could do incremental builds? 
I guess there should be a way to parse the given ant target and learn which exactly sub-targets/scripts to run and package war when I changes MyGoodStyle.less.

- Or maybe there could be some semi-automatic solution?
- Or if IntelliJ IDEA and ant aren't fit enough for the task, I am willing to try migrating to e.g. maven and Eclipse if there is a solution there.

Comment: Ant build file doesn't suit well for automatic importing in the IDE. IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support it. That would work for Gradle or Maven, though. For Ant you will have to configure the project and the artifacts manually, then automatic incremental builds and hot deployments will work: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html.

Comment: Yeah, that looks similar to what I am looking for if IDEA is indeed able to parse maven projects intelligently enough to perform incremental updates for e.g. resources. Unfortunately so far I failed to find an article confirming it. I guess just trying it could be faster.